# Issues related to creating mask of an RGB image in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, mask

I want to create a mask of a RGB image based on a pixel value but the following code segment throws error

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I can provide the image if it is at all required.

Here is the code segment

```
image = cv2.imread("abcd.png")
for k in range(image.shape[0]):
    for l in range(image.shape[1]):
        if(image[k][l]==[255,255,255]):
            mask[k][l]=255
        else:
            mask[k][l]=0
```

I wonder what is the problem in the code?

Comment: What is unclear in the error message?

Comment: The error is in the line ```if(image[k][l]==[255,255,255]):```

Comment: I assume it has problem to compare color with [255,255,255] and you may have to compare `R == 255 and G == 255 and B == 255`

Comment: You can compare the whole BGR triplet, if you do, what is given as a hint in the error message: `if (all(image[k][l] == [255, 255, 255]))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterating over pixels with `for` loops is seriously slow - try to get in the habit of vectorising your processing with Numpy.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Load image
image = cv2.imread("start.png")

# Mask of white pixels - elements are True where image is White
Wmask =(im[:, :, 0:3] == [255,255,255]).all(2) 

# Save as PNG
cv2.imwrite('result.png', (Wmask*255).astype(np.uint8))
```

So, starting with this image:

[image]

You will get this mask:

[image]

Comment: Hello. I do not understand what does `im[:, :, 0:3]` do ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a hint in above error itself. You can use `numpy.all()` to check if an image pixel is white or not.

**New code:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("image.png")
h, w = image.shape[:2]
mask = np.zeros((h, w))

for k in range(h):
    for l in range(w):
        if np.all(image[k][l]==255): # true if (image[k][l][0]==255 and image[k][l][1]==255 and image[k][l][1]==255)
           mask[k][l]=255
```