# How to generate a mask using Pillow's Image.load() function

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, image-manipulation

I want to create a mask based on certain pixel values. For example: every pixel where B > 200

The Image.load() method seems to be exactly what I need for identifying the pixels with these values, but I can't seem to figure out how to take all these pixels and create a mask image out of them.

```py
            R, G, B = 0, 1, 2

            pixels = self.input_image.get_value().load()
            width, height = self.input_image.get_value().size

            for y in range(0, height):
                for x in range(0, width):
                    if pixels[x, y][B] > 200:
                        print("%s - %s's blue is more than 200" % (x, y))
``
```

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/56787920/2836621

Comment: Thanks for that, that was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I meant for you to avoid `for` loops and just use Numpy. So, starting with this image:

[image]

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Open image
im = Image.open('colorwheel.png')

# Make Numpy array
ni = np.array(im)

# Mask pixels where Blue > 200
blues = ni[:,:,2]>200

# Save logical mask as PNG
Image.fromarray((blues*255).astype(np.uint8)).save('result.png')
```

[image]

If you want to make the masked pixels black, use:

```
ni[blues] = 0
Image.fromarray(ni).save('result.png')
```

[image]

---

You can make more complex, compound tests against ranges like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Open image
im = Image.open('colorwheel.png')

# Make Numpy array
ni = np.array(im)

# Mask pixels where 100 < Blue < 200
blues = ( ni[:,:,2]>100 ) & (ni[:,:,2]<200)

# Save logical mask as PNG
Image.fromarray((blues*255).astype(np.uint8)).save('result.png')
```

[image]

You can also make a condition on Reds, Greens and Blues and then use Numpy's `np.logical_and()` and `np.logical_or()` to make compound conditions, e.g.:

```
bluesHi = ni[:,:,2] > 200 
redsLo  = ni[:,:,0] < 50

mask = np.logical_and(bluesHi,redsLo)
```

Comment: Yeah I totally misread your answer in the other question. Thanks for clarifying! This is indeed way faster than for loops. How would you expand to change pixels in multiple channels and between certain values?

For example, every pixel where 

10 > R > 50
10 > G > 100
50 > B > 200